# Using vbscript to run elevated and wait for command to complete

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a vbscript that I call from Java to unzip a file and then use the files that are unzipped. I need to run the unzip in elevated mode. When I do, the vbscript does not wait for the files to be unzipped before returning, and the next command runs before the files are there.

Here is what I am doing at the moment:

Java:

```
public void unzipElevated( String fileName, String Target )
{
   String  unzipFile = "cscript " 
          + tmpDir.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + "RunElevated.vbs "
          + "UnzipFiles.vbs "    
          + fileName + " "
          + Target   + File.separator;
   ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

   Process p;
   try
   {
      p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( unzipFile );
      p.waitFor();

      InputStream s = p.getInputStream();
      Scanner     i = new Scanner( s );
      while (i.hasNextLine())
         lines.add( i.nextLine() );
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
   }
}
```

vbscript: (RunElevated.vbs)

```
' Run the script in elevated mode
'
' This will be needed to install programs into Program Files
prgName      = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
prgArgs      = ""
If Wscript.Arguments.Count > 1 Then
   For i = 1 To Wscript.Arguments.Count - 1
      prgArgs = prgArgs & " " & Wscript.Arguments.Item(i)
   Next
End If
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set fso      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath      = fso.GetParentFolderName (WScript.ScriptFullName)
If fso.FileExists(strPath & "\" & prgName) Then
   prgCmd = Chr(34) & strPath & "\" & prgName & Chr(34)
   If prgArgs <> "" Then
      prgCmd = prgCmd & " " & prgArgs
   End If 
   objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", prgCmd, "", "runas", 1
Else
   Wscript.Echo "Script file not found"
End If
```

vbscript: (UnzipFiles.vbs)

```
' unzip a file- for now assume that full paths will be provided
ZipFile  = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
Extract  = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If fso.FileExists( ZipFile ) Then
' If the extraction location does not exist create it.
   If NOT fso.FolderExists( Extract ) Then 
      fso.CreateFolder( Extract ) 
   End If 

' Do the extraction  
   set objShell   = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" ) 
   set FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace( ZipFile ).items 
   objShell.NameSpace( Extract ).CopyHere  FilesInZip, 16 

   Set objShell = Nothing 
Else
   Wscript.echo "Zip file not found"
End If

Set fso      = Nothing
```

I use wscript in RunElevated because I want to see the progress box from the uzip command, but not the cmd window. I use 16 in CopyHere to not prompt about overwriting files.

It works nicely EXCEPT it returns as soon as the zipping starts, which makes a mess of trying to use the unzipped files.

I have found the Run command, it has an option for waiting for the process to finish:

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "TestScript.vbs" intWindowStyle, bWaitOnReturn
```

which I assume would allow me (setting bWaitOnReturn to true) to have the vbscript wait until the one called finishes, but I don't see how to run in elevated mode using Run.

I've been looking, but I've not found a way to run elevated and wait for the process to finish. It seems like a pretty common requirement (whenever copying, unzipping, etc). I'm a vbscript novice, I either didn't find an answer or didn't recognize it when looking.

Could some vbscript guru help me out here?  Or if my Java is wrong, I'd be happy to have help there as well!

Comment: Why are you mixing technologies?  If you are using Java, why not stick to Java.  Or if VBScript, why use Java at all?

Comment: I suppose I should not have mentioned Java. I wrote the GUI wrapper around the vbscripts in Java. If I knew how to run elevated in Java, access the Windows unzip utility in Java, I'd not be using vbscript. Just running the vbscript parts runs into the problem of ShellExecute returning immediately.

Comment: I understand that.  But again, why use both?  If you're writing a GUI wrapper in Java, why not just write the whole thing in Java?

Comment: Btw, have you tried launching your Java executable with elevated privileges?  Any child process it creates should then also have elevated privileges.

Comment: I'm not really a Windows person. I've worked almost entirely with Linux. It would help to give me some tips on how to run my Java executable with elevated privleges. The scenario will be that the program will most likely be run from a user account. It then needs to prompt to run elevated and get about 200 MB copied to Program Files or Program Files (x86). It has to work on XP, Vista and Windows 7. Are you suggesting using ShellExecute to run java -jar myJavaApp? Or did you have a different method in mind?

Comment: Personally, I would compile my Java wrapper into an executable.  Then you could just right-click the executable and choose "Run as Administrator".  This makes it easy on the end-user as well.  ShellExecute or the Java CLI (with runas) will work, but those methods can get overly complicated.

Comment: I've noticed one problem with trying to run the whole application as administrator. Currently, if the user does not want to install in Program files, browse will bring up their directories, whereas once I am running as administrator, it brings up the administrators directories. Though I suppose I could include whether to run as administrator or not in the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a side-effect by design.